# How to simplify an expression involving several square roots without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$\frac{5 \sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-4\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}- \frac{4 \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}$$
This type of questions are common in the university entrance examinations in our country but the calculators are not allowed can someone help me to find the way to simplify the expression.

Comment: I don't see any equation, just a calculation. It's often helpful to use $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ to get off the $\sqrt{}$'s

Comment: One should start thinking in algebraic terms instead of numeric ones. A calculator can mostly help with the latter one, i.e. giving you an answer in the form of a decimal number as $3.523234...$. This will not help the general understanding. What is more important is to learn the *formal rules* like $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\cdot \sqrt b$ etc. In the higher levels of math education, what is important is that you can reduce your answer to $\sqrt 3$. Mostly noone cares at this point that this is roughly $1.7$. Why? Because $1.7$ is approximate, no matter how many digit you use. But $\sqrt3$ is exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your expression contains a typo :)

Actually we have to simplify
$$\frac{5 \sqrt{5}}{4\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)}- \frac{4 \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}$$

Notice that both fractions can be simplified multiplying numerator and denominator by

$\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)$

Indeed 
$$\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)=3\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{5}$$
the expression becomes
$$\frac{\left(5 \sqrt{5}\right)\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)}{4\sqrt 5}- \frac{4 \sqrt{5}\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)}{\sqrt 5}=\\=\frac{5 \left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)}{4}- 4\left(\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}\right)=\frac{21 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}}}{4}-\frac{11 \sqrt{3 \sqrt{5}}}{4}$$

If the $\sqrt{7}$ is not a typo the numerator is a bit more complicated, but the basics are always the same

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}{a - b}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{5 \sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-4\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}- \frac{4 \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}=\frac{5\sqrt7-16\sqrt5}{4(\sqrt{3\sqrt5}-\sqrt{2\sqrt5})}.$$

Comment: I also have the same thing but what is next

Comment: @R.Temur I think there is a mistake in the given. By the way, we can divide by $\sqrt[4]5$ the denominator and the nominator, but it's ugly already.

Comment: yes it seems to

Comment: It is not so ugly : $\frac{1}{4} \sqrt[4]{5} \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{35}-16\right)$. I started from your answer but I have to go right now. Start multiplying by the conjugate of denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{a\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt[4]{b}$

$$\tag1
\frac{5 \sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-4\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}- \frac{4 \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}}$$

$$\tag2
\frac{5\sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{3}\sqrt[4]{5}-4\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{5}}- \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt[4]{5}-\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

$$\tag3
\left(\frac{5\sqrt{7}}{4(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}- \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

$$\tag4
\left(\frac{5 \sqrt{7} - 16 \sqrt{5}}{4(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$$